# Having Trouble With A Simple C++ Program

Tags: c++, arrays, for-loop

I'm creating this very simple C++ program.
the program asks the user to enter a few integers and stores them in an array.but when a specific integer(for example 50)is entered,the input is ended and then,all of the integers are displayed on the screen except for 50.
for example:

input:

```
1
2
88
50
```

output:

```
1
2
88
```

the error i'm getting is when i use `cout` to print the array,all of numbers are shown,including 50 and numbers i did'nt even entered.

this is my code so far:

```html
#include<iostream>

int main() {
   int num[100];
   for(int i=0;i<=100;i++) {
      cin >> num[i];
      if (num[i]!=50) break;
   }
   for(int j=0;j<=100;j++) {
      cout << num[j] << endl;
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why are you displaying till 100?

Comment: what should i do to display til one number before 50?

Comment: Did you learn about the standard library and `std::vector` yet?

Comment: @RaphaelMiedl Yeah, I'm working on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You read up to 101 numbers, but if you enter 50 you break the loop and go for printing it. In the printing loop you go through all 101 numbers, but you actually may have not set all of them.

In the first loop count in a `count` variable the numbers you read until you meet 50 and in the printing loop just iterate `count-1` times.

Answer (score 3):

Change the program the following way

```
#include<iostream>

int main() 
{
    const size_t N = 100;
    int num[N];

    size_t n = 0;
    int value;
    while ( n < N && std::cin >> value && value != 50 ) num[n++] = value;

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ ) std::cout << num[i] << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Here in the first loop variable `n` is used to count the actual number of entered values. And then this variable is used as the upper bound for the second loop.

As for your program then the valid range of indices for the first loop is `0-99` and you have to output only whose elements of the array that were inputed.

Answer (score 3):

A do while loop is more suitable for your problem. The stop condition will check if the number fit inside the array (if k is not bigger than 100) and if number entered is 50.

```
    #include<iostream>
        using namespace std;
        int main() {

        int num[100];
        int k = 0;

   // A do while loop will be more suitable
      do{
          cin >> num[k++];
        }while(k<100&&num[k-1]!=50);

            for (int j = 0; j < k-1; j++) {
                cout << num[j] << endl;
            }
            return 0;
        }
```

Also, a better solution to get rid of 100 limitation is to use `std::vector` data structure that automatically adjust it's size, like this:

```
vector<int> num;
int temp;

do {
    cin >> temp;
    num.push_back(temp);
} while (temp != 50);
```

Note, you can use temp.size() to get the number of items stored.

Answer (score 2):

You have allocated an array of 100 integers on the stack. The values are not initialized to zero by default, so you end up having whatever was on the stack previously appear in your array.

You have also off-by-one in both of your loops, you allocated array of 100 integers so that means index range of 0-99.

As the question is tagged as C++, I would suggest that you leave the C-style array and instead use a `std::vector` to store the values. This makes it more flexible as you don't have to specify a fixed size (or manage memory) and you don't end up with uninitialized values.

Little example code (requires C++11 compiler):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> numbers; // Store the numbers here

    for(int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) // Ask a number 100 times
    {
        int n;
        std::cin >> n;
        if( n == 50 ) // Stop if user enters 50
            break;
        numbers.push_back(n); // Add the number to the numbers vector
    }

    for (auto n : numbers) // Print all the values in the numbers vector
        std::cout << n << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are just 2 changes in your code check it out :

```
int main() 
{
int num[100],i;             //initialize i outside scope to count number of inputs
for(i=0;i<100;i++) {
  cin >> num[i];
  if (num[i]==50) break;         //break if the entered number is 50 
}
for(int j=0;j<=i-1;j++) 
{
  cout << num[j] << endl;
}
return 0;
```

}

Comment: what about the overflow?

Comment: I used i to count the total inputs .So it would not overflow. see j<=i-1.@nilo

Comment: and the loop before that?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, others already pointed out the two mistakes. You should use `i < 100` in the loop conditions instead of `i <= 100` and you have to keep track of how many elements you entered.

Now let me add an answer how I think it would be better.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() {

    std::vector<int> numbers; // Create an empty vector.

    for (int temp;                  // a temp variable in the for loop.
        numbers.size() < 100 &&     // check that we have less than 100 elements.
        std::cin >> temp &&         // read in the temp variable,
                                    // and check if the read was a success.
        temp != 50)                 // lastly check that the value we read isn't 50.
    {
        numbers.push_back(temp); // Now we just add it to the vector.
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.size(); ++i)
        std::cout << numbers[i];  // Now we just print all the elements of
                                  // the vector. We only added correct items.
}
```

The above code doesn't even read anymore numbers after it found 50. And if you want to be able to enter any number of elements you just have to remove the check that we have less than 100 elements.

Now I commented the above code a bit much, if you compress it it'll reduce to just:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() {

    std::vector<int> numbers; // Create an empty vector.

    for (int temp; numbers.size() < 100 && std::cin >> temp && temp != 50)
        numbers.push_back(temp);

    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.size(); ++i)
        std::cout << numbers[i];
}
```

If you can use the C++11 standard it reduces to:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() {

    std::vector<int> numbers; // Create an empty vector.

    for (int temp; numbers.size() < 100 && std::cin >> temp && temp != 50)
        numbers.push_back(temp);

    for (int element : numbers)
        std::cout << element;
}
```

`for (auto element : numbers)` is new, it basically means for every int 'element' in 'numbers'.